# Table bootstrap vue

Tags: vue.js

I created a table with bootstrap vue. I would need the price value to increase based on the quantity selected. So if I select 2 products, the price will be multiplied by 2 and so on. My problem is that I can't access the value of the quantity cell.

```
<template v-slot:cell(price)="data">
            <span>{{data.item.price = data.item.price * value}}</span>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:cell(quantity)="data">
            <b-col sm="4">
              <b-form-input value="1" min="1" :max="data.item.quantity" type="number"></b-form-input>
            </b-col>
          </template>
```

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear. Why can't you add a v-model binding to the quantity input  (or equivalent, I'm making an assumption about b-form-input) and then use that instead of `value`?

Comment: because making a v model my value is passed to all the elements of the table in that input. I can't understand how to assign the value for each element.

Comment: Why not try making a separate component for each table row? Then each row will have its own quantity.

Comment: Based on this `{{ data.item.price = data.item.price * value }}`, you want to actually update the price in the object? Or do you only want it displayed?

Comment: the price for a unit remains unchanged, however the price multiplied by the selected quantity is shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a global value in your `data`, you should store the input value on each object. 
That way it's per-row.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        'price',
        'quantity',
        'total'
      ],
      items: [{
          price: 550,
          quantity: 5,
          amount: 1
        },
        {
          price: 295,
          quantity: 16,
          amount: 1
        },
        {
          price: 199,
          quantity: 3,
          amount: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.10.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.10.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template #cell(quantity)="{ item }">
     <b-input v-model="item.amount" min="1" :max="item.quantity" type="number" number></b-input>
    </template>
    <template #cell(total)="{ item }">
     {{ item.price * (item.amount || 1)}}
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, though as the table gets more complex I'd be inclined to create a row component.